# Angular ou AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Vi algumas perguntas aqui no site relacionadas a isso porém estava mais relacionado a atualizar de um para o outro e outras foram fechadas...

Quais as principais diferenças de um em relação ao outro?

Mesmo sendo uma versão mais antiga, o AngularJS pode ter pequenas atualizações? (tenho a impressão que durante a criação de um projeto usando o AngularJS tenha surgido uma atualização, mas pode ter sido só impressão)

Comment: Esta e uma pergunta baseada em opnião. Mas o angular e a tecnologia mais moderna e melhor para projetos novos, o angularjs somente para projetos legados ou times que não querem aprender a versão nova.

Comment: @EduardoVargas por que considera baseada em opinião?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico? Ainda não vejo motivo para ser considerada baseada em opinião

Comment: preguntas dos tipos qual o melhor framework js? ou qual e melhor angular ou react? Ou nesse caso angular vs angularJs sempre vão ser subjetivos. Pois nunca se sabe pra quer sera aplicado ou as espcifcacoes do projeto. Alem de que as perguntas no SO são pra ser consideradas artefatos para serem usados por outros e como o mundo web  e estes freameworks estão sempre mudando e impossível ter esse tipo de resposta.

Comment: Basicamente a mesma coisa da sua pergunta no meta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6891/baseada-em-opini%C3%A3o-ou-n%C3%A3o

Comment: Por exemplo eu posso falar que uma das vantagens do typescritpt invés do js mas vc pode achar isso uma desvantagem. Ou que ele usa observables invés de promises etc mas vc acha promises melhor. etc.

Comment: Não busco qual é a mehlor e sim suas diferenças, o que uma tem e outra, para poder eu mesmo devidir qual é a melhor pra cada situação. Citarar as principais diferenças entre ambas seria subjetivo?

Comment: Então refaz sua pergunta pq vc perguntou quais serias as vantagens e desvantagens  E quais caso usar cada.

Comment: @EduardoVargas editado, se quiser pode adicionar/melhorar algo na pergunta

Comment: Eu prefiro VueJS e AXIOS (CDN)
https://br.vuejs.org/
https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As principais diferenças são:

- [Angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki): Apesar de no angularjs vc conseguir gerar o projeto com ferramentas como o [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) o angular 2 tem o angular-cli que facilita não só ter uma maneira padrão de gerar projetos também como qualquer outro codigo usando o [generate](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate). Por exemplo para gerar components, services, etc. Alem dele poder compilar seu código pra produção ou servir o mesmo com hot-reload que deixa o desenvolvimento bem mais rápido.
- [RxJs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library): O angular usa por padrão o rxjs para fazer os dados fluírem por sua aplicação. O estilo de programação funcional reativa por mais que complicado no começo possibilita códigos bem mais elegantes e muito mais controle no fluxo dos dados da sua aplicação.
- Performance: O angular possui "out-of-the-box" uma performance bem melhor que o js e alem disso possibilita varias técnicas pra deixar a performance ainda melhor como AOT ou lazy-loading.
- [Suporte e novas features](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c): Depois do lançamento da versao 1.7 do angularJs a equipe ira parar com novas features e terá somente bugfixes. Sendo assim sera bem mais dificil de ter uma compatibilidade com novas tecnologias tipo PWA, etc. Enquanto o angular esta a todo o vapor com releases semestrais com novas tecnologias e features alem de melhoras em performance.

Outros pontos: o Angular e bem mais fácil de testar. E também a comunidade esta cada vez mais rápido [migrando](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=BR&q=angular,angularjs) pro angular.